# How to get multiple columns with a single group by in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table that looks like below

```
               Table "public.test_systems"
           Column            |          Type          | Modifiers 
-----------------------------+------------------------+-----------
 rid                         | integer                | not null
 r_osname                    | character varying(255) | 
 r_health                    | integer                | 
 r_patch                     | bigint                 | 
 r_loc                       | character varying(255) |
```

Here each row in the table depicts a system. Now if I want to find out how many systems by unique OS names, I do a query like below

```
select r_osname, count(*) as total_systems from test_systems group by r_osname;
```

So I get a result like below

```
                    r_osname                   | total_systems 
-----------------------------------------------+--------------
 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS                            |           18
 Windows 10 Pro                                |            2
 CentOS Linux                                  |            1
 Windows Server 2019                           |            3
 Mac OS X - High Sierra                        |            2
```

Now I want to run the same query but for multiple columns. In other words I want to get multiple columns with a single `groupby`. But Postgres forces me to mention the additional columns in the `groupby` too.

I tried `distinct on` in my query like below

```
select distinct on (r_osname) test_systems.* from test_systems order by os_name;
```

I got same number of rows (partial success) but can't get the `count(*)` as an additional column.

The final result could look something like below (on including additional columns like `r_health` and `r_loc`)

```
                    r_osname                   |           r_health                |   r_loc            | total_systems 
-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------+--------------
 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS                            | 1012                              | NYC                |            18
 Windows 10 Pro                                | 1121                              | LON                |             2
 CentOS Linux                                  | 1255                              | DEL                |             1
 Windows Server 2019                           | 1451                              | HYD                |             3
 Mac OS X - High Sierra                        | 1120                              | LA                 |             2
```

How do I get the expected result?

Comment: *But Postgres forces me to mention the additional columns in the groupby too* did you try it?

Comment: @forpas Yes I have to end up doing something like `select r_osname, r_health, r_loc, count(*) as total_systems from test_systems group by r_osname, r_health, r_loc;`
`

Comment: This is exactly what you should do.

Comment: @forpas then how do I get the expected table as I mentioned in my question? Basically I want to get the same table but with additional columns. Currently adding multiple groupby changes the result.

Comment: The additional columns are r_health and r_loc which the query returns. What is the problem?

Comment: @forpas The number of rows increases since its no more based on the first groupby.

Comment: Then you did not explain correctly your requirement. Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: @forpas I have already posted two samples that depicts initial result and expected result. Let me know if I am missing out anything. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: The expected results that you posted do not explain how they will be produced? For example why do you want r_health=1012 for Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS if in the table there are other values for r_health (the same for the other column r_loc )

Answer (score 0):

You need a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to make this work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    r_osname, r_health, r_loc,
    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY r_osname, r_health, r_loc)
FROM test_systems
```

Depending on which combination of values in the columns you want to include in the result you can play with the `DISTINCT ON (...)` clause. Without a `DISTINCT` clause you will get as many rows as there are in the table (26 in your example) but if you want only 1 row for each OS then you should use `DISTINCT ON (r_osname)`. The row that will be returned depends on the `ORDER BY` clause - if none is given then the first row will be returned for each set of rows which have the same `r_osname` but there will be no way to predict which row that will be.

Comment: Hi Patrick, this seems to give a long result (more rows being generated). The only additional thing I did is add a `where` clause in both the queries (single vs multiple columns) and was expecting same number of rows. Did I miss out anything?

Comment: ORG Query: 

`select r_osname, count(*) as total_systems from test_systems group by r_osname where current_date - to_timestamp(cast(r_patch/1000 as bigint))::date >= 7;` 

UPDATED Query 

`SELECT DISTINCT r_osname, r_health, r_loc, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY r_osname, r_health, r_loc) FROM test_systems where current_date - to_timestamp(cast(r_patch/1000 as bigint))::date >= 7`  

`r_patch` stores date in epoch format FYI